# The width of a custom view used in a Crouton is being incorrectly calculated

Tags: android, android-fragments, crouton

I've created a custom view to display using the Crouton library. This view has some margin, a background and a TextView with MATCH_PARENT width. This TextView is multiline and has a left drawable.

The problem I'm facing is that when I show it with the Crouton, the TextView's width is calculated incorrectly, making the text to cut off. It's very strange because it only happens the first time my Fragment is created. If I rotate the screen to landscape and rotate again to portrait, it shows normally. I'm showing the crouton inside the onStart() method of my fragment, that I add to the Activity on runtime.

The following screenshot shows the first appearance of the crouton.

[image]

And the following shows the appearance of the crouton after rotating the screen two times.

[image]

I'm creating the crouton the following way:

```
Crouton.make(getActivity(), inflater.inflate(R.layout.crouton_explicacao_qr_code, container, false), container).show();
```

If I inflate the custom view manually, adding it to the container (a FrameLayout), it works like the second screenshot.

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.crouton_explicacao_qr_code, container, true)
```

So, it doesn't seem to be related to my custom view.

If I inflate the custom view with a null container, it loses its margins, since it doesn't know where it's going to be added in order to prepare the margins.

Can anyone help me with that? Is that a Crouton's bug?

UPDATE:

This is the custom view I'm using for the Crouton:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              style="?croutonQrCode">

    <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/explicacao_qr_code"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_qrcode_puro"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/thin_padding"
        style="?textCrouton" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The styles used in this layout are the following:

```
<style name="crouton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/crouton_background</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/crouton_margin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/crouton_margin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/crouton_margin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/crouton_margin</item>
</style>

<style name="crouton.qrcode">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">40dp</item>
</style>

<style name="text">
    <item name="typeface">roboto_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
</style>

<style name="text.crouton">
    <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/title</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title_font_size</item>
    <item name="typeface">roboto_regular</item>
</style>
```

My container is a FrameLayout, where I replace my fragments. The following is my Activity's layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.meubilhete.ui.DrawerActivity">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/screen_background" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What is your container? Also, please show the xml of crouton_explicacao_qr_code

Comment: My container is a FrameLayout, that I use to put all my fragments, replacing them. I have basically an unique Activity with lots of Fragments. I'll update my question with the XML you asked.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer, I've updated my answer to include what you asked for.